# Use .SaveCopyAs

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel file template and at 11:50 PM ET Time I want it to save a copy of the whole day's file as the date it was used. Only problem I have is that it's not saving. No error messages and nothing on any folders. Also, the file needs to be saved in a different location. Anyone care to help?

Here's a copy of the code:

```
sub end_of_day()
Dim path As String
Dim filename As String

path = "\\myfile\project\"
filename = "Log as of " & Sheet2.Range("N1").Value & " ET"


If Sheet2.Range("O1").Value = Sheet2.Range("T1") Then

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=path & filename
End If
End Sub
```

Notes:
I live in a different timezone that's why in my excel sheet, I have two cells that contains the current ET time and the ET time it compares to so that it'll start saving a copy of it.

**N1** has the ET format date mmddyyyy (06232016)
**O1** is the current eastern time hh:mm AM/PM (11:50 PM) and **T1** has the constant time 11:50 PM.

Am I missing anything for this to work?Appreciate your response.

**EDIT:**

I apologize everyone that I was not clear. This workbook is being opened every 10 minutes using task scheduler then run all the modules it has inside. It'll gather the extracted data during that time until 11:50 PM (sorry I typed AM) where it'll save itself as the end of day's worth of data it gathered then start running the new day's at 12 AM. For this reason, I want to save a copy of the file and not touch the workbook as it will act as the template.

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly how you triggering the sub to run at your specified time?

Comment: How does this Sub get run? You would need it to run continuously for it to happen at 11:50.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right you are expecting this to fire an event at 11.50. If statements don't work like that, the process would have to be constantly monitoring the time. Why can't you use a scheduled task to do this?

Comment: yes, sorry I did not add that part but this file is being triggered using task scheduler every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that your sub is not running as you expect it to, subs will only run as they are called. As you have used an `If` statement to check the time and do your action, the only way to get this to work would be to place it in an infinite loop. This would be a very inefficient way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Instead of checking the time over and over and doing the save when the time is 11:50, you could instead schedule your sub to run at that time. The ideal way of doing this would be to place the following sub in `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:50:00"), "end_of_day"
End Sub
```

This will schedule the macro to run at 11:50 once you open the workbook, without having to do anything your sub will run at 11:50. This time will be the local time of the machine you are using the workbook on, so will need to be adjusted if needed.

You should also remove your `If` statement from your `end_of_day` sub as it is no longer required.

Something worth noting is that time 11:50 AM is 10 minutes before midday, however it seems like you want this to be run at the end of day i.e. midnight? In this case your time should be "23:50:00"

Comment: I apologize that I was not clear. This excel file is opened every 10 minutes using the task scheduler. So I call this module along with the others I have inside the workbook using the workbook_open sub. At that time, it'll save all of the gathered data it had on that particular day and at 12mn of the new day, it'll run again as a new file. that's why i did not want the template to do .saveas .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the insights provided. The file is now working fine. I just modified the `If` statement. I just added a "greater than" sign on the code then it worked fine. It saves when its time and just goes on if it still isn't.

```
sub end_of_day()
Dim path As String
Dim filename As String

path = "\\myfile\project\"
filename = "Log as of " & Sheet2.Range("N1").Value & " ET"


If Sheet2.Range("O1").Value >= Sheet2.Range("T1") Then

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=path & filename
End If
End Sub
```